# Getting mailbox connection type

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, imap, pop3

I am looking for a way to detect which connection method is used to connect to a mailbox, for example:

- Exchange
- POP3
- IMAP

Is there any way I can do this using power shell? Everywhere just tells me how to enable that option for the mailbox.

Comment: What data do you have for the mailbox? A e-mail address and that's all? If yes, the data on how to access that mailbox may be confidential.

Comment: We own the mailboxes, some of our clients are connecting to our exchange via pop3 or imap, we would like to know how they are connecting. I will be running this script on their machines.

Comment: So you just need to query their connection method, right?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`Get-ConnectionByClientTypeReport`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj873753%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) cmdlet to retrieve that data on your server side.

Comment: That is correct, is there a way that we can do the mentioned on the clients machine?

Comment: Do you know whether they all use Outlook, or a variety of email clients is expected?

Comment: They all use outlook

Comment: You need to query the registry keys [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx) HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles for Outlook 2013, HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles for Outlook 2010 and below. Note though, there might be more than a single profile, so you can potentially disclose your clients' personal data. I'd say you'd better use the server-side script and not bother with clients' PCs.

Answer (score 1):

The Account class from the Outlook object model provides the [AccountType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867094(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a constant in the OlAccountType enumeration that indicates the type of the Account. Can be one of the following values:

- olEas - 4 - An account that uses Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) on mobile devices.
- olExchange - 0 - An Exchange account.
- olHttp - 3 - An HTTP account.
- olImap - 1 - An IMAP account.
- olOtherAccount - 5 - Other or unknown account.
- olPop3 - 2 - A POP3 account.

Answer (score 0):

Read the PR_MDB_PROVIDER property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x34140102`) from any object in that store (message, folder, store) using PropertyAccess.GetProperty and convert it to a hex string using PropertyAccess.BinaryToString.

E.g. for an Exchange store, the value of the property will be 5494A1C0297F101BA58708002B2A2517, for a PST store - 4E495441F9BFB80100AA0037D96E0000.